# "While" in algorithm stays in the same line

Tags: beamer, algorithms

I can't figure out why my "While" stays in the same line. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{comment}


\captionsetup{labelsep = period} 


\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\NoCaptionOfAlgo \caption{\textbf{Algorithm:} Finding $z$} 
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require{$x, y$}
\Ensure{$z$}
\State $s \gets 0$
\State $j \gets 1$  \hfill\COMMENT{iteration number}
\While{$s <  k$}{
  \State $t \gets 1$
  \State $f \gets true$
  \While{$(t \ge 4)$ and $f$} 
     {
       \State $x \gets 3$  
       \If{$f$ is negative}
            {
             \State $t \gets f-1$
             \State $f \gets$ false
            }
       \State $t \gets 3$
      }
  \State Assign $x$ to $y$
  \State $s \gets 5$
  \State $j \gets 55$
  }
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not compile. There is no point in worrying about which lines the `while` is in as long as there are errors. After an error, latex only syntax checks the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output.

In this case the error message is pretty clear:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ...State $j \gets 1$ \COMMENT 
                                                  {iteration number} \While ...
l.50 \end{frame}
```

which tells you that the macro `\COMMENT` simply does not exist. Instead you have to use one of the many comment macros the `algorithm2e` package defines, e.g. `\tcc*{...}` for right aligned inline comments.

In a pure `algorithm2e` syntax:

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{comment}


\captionsetup{labelsep = period} 


\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\NoCaptionOfAlgo \caption{\textbf{Algorithm:} Finding $z$} 
\Input{$x, y$}
\Output{$z$}

$s \gets 0$

$j \gets 1$ \tcc*{iteration number}

\While{$s <  k$}{
  $t \gets 1$
  
  $f \gets true$
  
  \While{$(t \ge 4)$ and $f$} 
     {
        $x \gets 3$  
      
       \If{$f$ is negative}
            {
              $t \gets f-1$
              
              $f \gets$ false
            }
        $t \gets 3$
      }
   Assign $x$ to $y$
   
   $s \gets 5$
   
   $j \gets 55$
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But in this case "while" and "if" are still in the same line. They do not go to the next line (like after assign "true" to f).

Comment: Also, it is strange but my code did compile in Overleaf with the previous command \hfill\COMMENT{iteration number}

Comment: Your code did NOT compile on overleaf, overleaf is just very good at hiding error messages

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to move "while" and "if" where they should be? (next line)

Comment: @Vika See my updated answer with just the `algorithm2e` syntax